# How to add query results into a new array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I wrote the query below to get all IDs in the table user that match the condition. How can I add the results into a new array.

```
$sql_req = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT user.ID FROM user WHERE class = 'TEST' ");
```

I read an instruction on Codex. It said I could use foreach to get the results.

```
foreach ($sql_req as $data) {
 $id = $data->ID;
}
```

It works but $id is not an array. $is contains only one value. How can I add all values into a new array? Thank you.

Comment: `$id[] = $data->ID;`

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna want to have an array to store the values in.

```
$storageArray = [];
foreach ($sql_req as $data) {
  $storageArray[] = $data->ID;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want an array of id's you want to do this:

```
$cnt = 0;
foreach ($sql_req as $data) {
 $id[$cnt] = $data->ID;
++$cnt;
}
```

this will give you an array of the id's in a table indexed by integers

if you want to do this without the counter you can go:

```
$array = Array();
    foreach ($sql_req as $data) {
     array_push($array , $data->id);
    }
```

Comment: Can we just do that without $cnt?

foreach ($sql_req as $data) {
 $id[] = $data->ID;
}

Comment: I mean do we need the variable $cnt? Can we just leave $id[ ] ?